# Traer un elemento desde un Array con find Vuejs

Tags: javascript, array, vue.js

Hola estoy intentando eliminar un elemento de mi Array **Productos**. Y ya lo pude hacer con el método **splice**. El problema es que tengo una variable llamada **total** que se encarga de sumar todos los productos en ese array, entonces a la hora de apretar el boton que se encarga de borrar ese dato, se elimina pero mi variable total sigue sumando ese resultado del elemento borrado.

dejo una foto para que entiendan mejor

**en esta foto estoy agregando elementos a mi array productos y se van sumando todos los que se agregan**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**acá elimine el producto de nombre PAN y el método splice funciono pero me sigue mostrando el total de los 3 productos**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces para poder eliminar el dato también de mi variable TOTAL estaba queriendo filtrar el elemento por medio de su index, así que decidí utilizar el **método find**

entonces esta es mi funcion **eliminar**

```
eliminar(index){
    this.productos.splice(index, 1)
    // aca esta el problema :(
    const nuevoArray = this.productos.find( item => item.index == index)
    
    console.log(nuevoArray);
  }
```

pero no puedo hacer que funcione el **método find** ¿que estoy haciendo mal?
en ves de traerme un elemento solo me muestra **undefined** en consola

Comment: No sé cómo estás guardando el valor total pero creo que lo más apropiado sería utilizar una computed property basada en el array de productos. De esta manera, al modificar el array de productos, la computed property se dispara y el valor se recalcula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/splice), aparte de eliminar los elementos que indiques, también los devuelve, solo necesitas asignarlo a una variable:

```
eliminar(index){
    const nuevoArray = this.productos.splice(index, 1)
    console.log(nuevoArray);
}
```

En caso de que requieras el uso de `.find()`, el problema es que primero eliminas el elemento, el método no lo encuentra y devuelve `undefined`. Busca y después elimina:

```
eliminar(index){
    const nuevoArray = this.productos.find( item => item.index == index)
    this.productos.splice(index, 1)
    console.log(nuevoArray);
}
```

Comment: gracias, deje el find de lado, y termine usando el splice como me aconsejaste.
mi funcion quedo asi 
`const nuevoArray = this.productos.splice(index, 1) 
this.total -= nuevoArray[index].total;`